# How can i add email function on my landing page website? without backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, email, email-client

How can i add email function on my landing page website? i want that if i user enter his email than his email come to me so that i can contact him so how can i do that with a backend i have tried to use emailjs but its not working can anyone can pls do that in my code? can anyone can tell how to do it without backend i want to do it will emailjs i have given you details

## my code

```
import React from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

function Newsletter() {

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('service_uzcgjtf', 'template_izso05g', form.current, 'HXOYlFkZOUDFI1oCe')
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.text);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.text);
      });
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6">
        <div className="pb-12 md:pb-20">

          {/* CTA box */}
          <div className="relative bg-gray-900 rounded py-10 px-8 md:py-16 md:px-12 shadow-2xl overflow-hidden" data-aos="zoom-y-out">

            {/* Background illustration */}
            <div className="absolute right-0 bottom-0 pointer-events-none hidden lg:block" aria-hidden="true">
              <svg width="428" height="328" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <defs>
                  <radialGradient cx="35.542%" cy="34.553%" fx="35.542%" fy="34.553%" r="96.031%" id="ni-a">
                    <stop stopColor="#DFDFDF" offset="0%" />
                    <stop stopColor="#4C4C4C" offset="44.317%" />
                    <stop stopColor="#333" offset="100%" />
                  </radialGradient>
                </defs>
                <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                  <g fill="#FFF">
                    <ellipse fillOpacity=".04" cx="185" cy="15.576" rx="16" ry="15.576" />
                    <ellipse fillOpacity=".24" cx="100" cy="68.402" rx="24" ry="23.364" />
                    <ellipse fillOpacity=".12" cx="29" cy="251.231" rx="29" ry="28.231" />
                    <ellipse fillOpacity=".64" cx="29" cy="251.231" rx="8" ry="7.788" />
                    <ellipse fillOpacity=".12" cx="342" cy="31.303" rx="8" ry="7.788" />
                    <ellipse fillOpacity=".48" cx="62" cy="126.811" rx="2" ry="1.947" />
                    <ellipse fillOpacity=".12" cx="78" cy="7.072" rx="2" ry="1.947" />
                    <ellipse fillOpacity=".64" cx="185" cy="15.576" rx="6" ry="5.841" />
                  </g>
                  <circle fill="url(#ni-a)" cx="276" cy="237" r="200" />
                </g>
              </svg>
            </div>

            <div className="relative flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-between items-center">

              {/* CTA content */}
              <div className="text-center lg:text-left lg:max-w-xl">
                <h3 className="h3 text-white mb-2">Powering your business</h3>
                <p className="text-gray-300 text-lg mb-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit nemo expedita voluptas culpa sapiente.</p>

                {/* CTA form */}
                <form className="w-full lg:w-auto">
                  <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row justify-center max-w-xs mx-auto sm:max-w-md lg:mx-0">
                    <input type="email" className="form-input w-full appearance-none bg-gray-800 border border-gray-700 focus:border-gray-600 rounded-sm px-4 py-3 mb-2 sm:mb-0 sm:mr-2 text-white placeholder-gray-500" placeholder="Your email…" aria-label="Your email…" onSubmit={sendEmail} />
                    <a className="btn text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 shadow" href="#0">Subscribe</a>
                  </div>
                  {/* Success message */}
                  {/* <p className="text-sm text-gray-400 mt-3">Thanks for subscribing!</p> */}
                  <p className="text-sm text-gray-400 mt-3">7 days free trial. No credit card required.</p>
                </form>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Newsletter;
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not add spam text. The warning is there for a reason

Comment: @evolutionxbox i have not added spam text it will edited it also i have just added because stackover is not allowing me to upload question

Comment: Did you take a look at [their documentation](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/)? If so, which bit were you stuck on?

Comment: @phuzi i want to do this on react

Comment: Put your onSubmit handler on the form element.

Answer (score 0):

`emailjs-com` package is deprecated use the latest `@emailjs/browser`

This is the sample code can be found in the link :
[emailjs/browser code example](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/reactjs/)

Hope this answer your question.

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';

function Newsletter() {

 const form = useRef();

 const sendEmail = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'TEMPLATE_ID', 
form.current, 'PUBLIC_KEY')
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.text);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error.text);
  });
};

return (
      <section>
        <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6">
          <div className="pb-12 md:pb-20">

            {/* CTA box */}
            <div className="relative bg-gray-900 rounded py-10 px-8 md:py-16 md:px-12 shadow-2xl overflow-hidden" data-aos="zoom-y-out">

              {/* Background illustration */}
              <div className="absolute right-0 bottom-0 pointer-events-none hidden lg:block" aria-hidden="true">
                <svg width="428" height="328" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <defs>
                    <radialGradient cx="35.542%" cy="34.553%" fx="35.542%" fy="34.553%" r="96.031%" id="ni-a">
                      <stop stopColor="#DFDFDF" offset="0%" />
                      <stop stopColor="#4C4C4C" offset="44.317%" />
                      <stop stopColor="#333" offset="100%" />
                    </radialGradient>
                  </defs>
                  <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                    <g fill="#FFF">
                      <ellipse fillOpacity=".04" cx="185" cy="15.576" rx="16" ry="15.576" />
                      <ellipse fillOpacity=".24" cx="100" cy="68.402" rx="24" ry="23.364" />
                      <ellipse fillOpacity=".12" cx="29" cy="251.231" rx="29" ry="28.231" />
                      <ellipse fillOpacity=".64" cx="29" cy="251.231" rx="8" ry="7.788" />
                      <ellipse fillOpacity=".12" cx="342" cy="31.303" rx="8" ry="7.788" />
                      <ellipse fillOpacity=".48" cx="62" cy="126.811" rx="2" ry="1.947" />
                      <ellipse fillOpacity=".12" cx="78" cy="7.072" rx="2" ry="1.947" />
                      <ellipse fillOpacity=".64" cx="185" cy="15.576" rx="6" ry="5.841" />
                    </g>
                    <circle fill="url(#ni-a)" cx="276" cy="237" r="200" />
                  </g>
                </svg>
              </div>

              <div className="relative flex flex-col lg:flex-row justify-between items-center">

                {/* CTA content */}
                <div className="text-center lg:text-left lg:max-w-xl">
                  <h3 className="h3 text-white mb-2">Powering your business</h3>
                  <p className="text-gray-300 text-lg mb-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit nemo expedita voluptas culpa sapiente.</p>

                  {/* CTA form */}
                  <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail} className="w-full lg:w-auto">
                    <div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row justify-center max-w-xs mx-auto sm:max-w-md lg:mx-0">
                      <input type="email" className="form-input w-full appearance-none bg-gray-800 border border-gray-700 focus:border-gray-600 rounded-sm px-4 py-3 mb-2 sm:mb-0 sm:mr-2 text-white placeholder-gray-500" placeholder="Your email…" aria-label="Your email…" />
                      <a className="btn text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 shadow" href='#' onClick={sendEmail}>Subscribe</a>
                    </div>
                    {/* Success message */}
                    {/* <p className="text-sm text-gray-400 mt-3">Thanks for subscribing!</p> */}
                    <p className="text-sm text-gray-400 mt-3">7 days free trial. No credit card required.</p>
                  </form>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
 );
}

export default Newsletter;
```

Comment: see my edited question pls its showing like this what can i do?

Comment: please `useRef` and  add the refernce of current form `<form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>`. The email row is collapsed because of the classname added there. `flex` and `flex-col` use the `absolute` or vice versa.
Please add the onSubmit handler in the form tag so it can send the email.

Comment: can you answer it by writing the code in answer

Comment: edited the answers please check

Comment: not working can we connect personally?

Comment: you can check the github repo https://github.com/Nilay2006/myproject12  pls comit it

Comment: Created PR
https://github.com/syblus446/myproject12/pull/1/files Review the changes. And make an account on `https://dashboard.emailjs.com/sign-in` to get the PublicKey, ServiceId and templateId and use these credentials in SendEmail function.